# Page.InitComplete handler is not executed

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I've run into a weird problem while developing a control. I've registered a handler for **Page.InitComplete** event from the control, but the handler is not executed. I need the handler to be executed exactly on **InitComplete** event, because I depend on complex application architecture.

My code looks like this (This code is placed inside my control class):

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    this.Page.InitComplete += (sender, args) => OnInitComplete(args);
}
```

However **OnInitComplete** is never entered.

If it is somehow possible I would like to find the way to register my handler to Page.InitComplete event without using my own events & weird hacks.

Apart from that I'm curious about the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: Thought first I could reproduce it, but nope. Works perfectly for me with the code you provided. (.NET 4.0) The error has to lie somewhere else. Can you provide more code so we can reproduce it?

Comment: @atticae Updated the question. I'm sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: @danyloid could you add your solution as an answer below so you can accept it?

Comment: @markc i'll do that after 8 hours, as I have not enough reputation to do this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm sorry - my fault**. The problem was in custom PageBase class :

```
protected override void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FormAction) && FormActionInitComplete != null)
    {
        FormActionInitComplete(FormActionSender, FormAction, FormActionValue);
    }
}
```

The **Page.OnInitComplete** method is implemented in the following way :

```
protected virtual void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) {
    EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)Events[EventInitComplete];
    if (handler != null) { 
        handler(this, e);
    } 
}
```

and in the overriden method of the PageBase there was no call of the **base.OnInitComplete** method - that is why the event was not raised.